# virtual hostname instead of i.p. address in mediawiki

Tags: apache2, mediawiki

I am trying to replace my i.p. address from my mediawiki with a virtual hostname. My system information are

O.S.: Opensuse 13.1 
Mediawiki: 1.26.1 
apache2 and mysql

I have edited the /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/mydomain.conf file like this

```
<VirtualHost 123.456.78.90>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.mylabwiki.org
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/mylabwiki
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myabwiki-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mylabwiki-access_log combined
    HostnameLookups Off
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerSignature On

<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -Includes
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/mylabwiki">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted  
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have edited the /etc/apache2/listen.conf file like this
`NameVirtualHost 123.456.78.90`

Then I have executed

```
vi /etc/hosts
123.456.78.90   www.mylabwiki.org
```

Then I restarted the apache2
    `service apache2 restart`

My problem is, it works only locally. If I use the browser from the host computer, the domain 'www.mylabwiki.org' works properly.But, if I type from a remote computer www.mylabwiki.org and try to connect, it says that the url doesn't exist. However, if I type http://123.456.78.90/ then works perfect from the remote computer. Can anyone tell me where did I miss something! I can feel that I am just one step away, but unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that www.mylabwiki.org is known only on your localhost, because you edited the /etc/hosts to have a local DNS resolution. Your remote computer do not get that information to know where to go.

There is 3 ways to solve the issue:

- you edit the /etc/hosts on the remote computer as well, but that means it will work on your localhost and remote computer, but not on nay other. So a real solution.
- you have a DNS local server, and you edit the server to resolve the name to the IP address. That will work for all computers on your network, not the outside world.
- you record this information in a domain name provide like name.com (or any other), so anyone in the world would know how to resolve the domain to the IP address. For sure it means the IP/computer can be accessed from outside your network.

Comment: I have understand the first two points, but I am not sure about the third point ! If you don't mind could you please tell me a bit more about the third one ! @cyrille

Comment: @Mon - If you register (or own) a domain at a registar, you can record a DNS that everyone can see. For example, I own the domain autodesk.io which I registered at name.com. I got a DNS record posted there which says extract.autodesk.io -> 52.34.82.112, that means anyone browser will resolve extract.autodesk.io to the IP address and then can connect to the server. I got the same for pier9.autodesk.io, gallery.autodesk.io, etc... - the difference is that is not computer specific.